# Delete rows with grep() and lapply with data.table

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I'm learning how data tables work and I'm trying to use `grep()` on two columns (`id1` and `id2`) to delete rows that don't return `TRUE`.

I know I have to use the function `lapply()` but it always returns the followed error :

```
argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I tried this (and I know it's wrong) :

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, grepl(id1, id2)), by= id]
```

The data I'm working on :

```
structure(list(id = c(52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 54L, 54L, 84L, 84L, 
87L, 87L, 129L, 129L, 130L, 130L, 130L), id1 = c("8113H187", 
"3505H6", "3505H6", "3505H6", "3505H6", "3505H6", "3505H6", "3505H6", 
"8113H187", "8113H187", "3505H6", "3505H6", "3505H6", "3505H6", 
"3505H6"), id2 = c("3505H6856", "3505H6856", "3505H6856", "3505H6856", 
"3505H67158", "3505H67158", "3505H63188", "3505H63188", "3505H64691", 
"3505H64691", "3505H664133", "3505H664133", "3505H658134", "3505H658134", 
"3505H658134")), .Names = c("id", "id1", "id2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000064f0788>)
```

Comment: `grepl` pattern argument isn't vectorized. Try something like `library(stringi) ; DT[, stri_detect_fixed(id2, id1)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DT[mapply( grepl, id1, id2), ]

#     id    id1         id2
# 1:  52 3505H6   3505H6856
# 2:  52 3505H6   3505H6856
# 3:  52 3505H6   3505H6856
# 4:  54 3505H6  3505H67158
# 5:  54 3505H6  3505H67158
# 6:  84 3505H6  3505H63188
# 7:  84 3505H6  3505H63188
# 8: 129 3505H6 3505H664133
# 9: 129 3505H6 3505H664133
# 10: 130 3505H6 3505H658134
# 11: 130 3505H6 3505H658134
# 12: 130 3505H6 3505H658134
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Map` to do compare the corresponding elements in 'id1' as `pattern` to the elements in  'ID2'

```
DT[unlist(Map(grepl, id1, id2))]
```